# EntityFramework Code First: how to explicitly specify the keys in two objects for communication?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, code-first

For example, the `User` can have multiple `Orders`. But the `User` has both `Id` and `UserId` (so it's necessary, otherwise there is no way).
To make a connection, you need to add in the `Order` object after `UserId` and `User` for the link. How do I specify this field to which specific field of the `User` object to bind?

Comment: English please.

Comment: I have two tables(User and Order). User may have several orders. Also user have fields Id and UserId. What attribute set to Order's filed User so that he can contact to User's filed UserId?

Comment: can you update the question as well with the description? Looks like it was translated by some online translator.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to link users to orders. Each user can have multiple orders. So, the classes might look something like this:

```
class User{
[Key]
public int Id{get;set;}

// Other properties
}

class Order{
[Key]
public int Id{get;set;}

public int UserId{ge;set;} // EF will understand that you want to link Order and User from this name

[ForeignKey(UserId)]
public User User{get;set;}// This will be your navigation property

// Other properties
}
```

I have typed the code here itself so there may be errors. Also, take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx) page for various data annotations available.

Comment: Order.UserId will refer to User.Id? I need to Order.UserId to refer to the User.UserId, however, in order to have an User.Id.

Comment: @AnotherUser Yes. You need to decorate the UserId field in user class with Key attribute